# Terminating main thread from child thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a GUI thread and Main thread. After closing a window I have method called inside the GUI thread. I would like to propagate this to Main thread to end its work. Main thread is doing several steps, so I am able to set stop_event, but I do not want to check after each line of code for Main thread if stop_event is set.

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is just to terminate main thread from the child thread, try the below.

```
import threading
import signal
import time
import os


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=child).start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        # KeyboardInterrupt happens by `signal.SIGINT` from the child thread.
        print('Main thread handle something before it exits')
    print('End main')

def child():
    print('Run child')
    time.sleep(2)
    # Send a signal `signal.SIGINT` to main thread.
    # The signal only head for main thread.
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
    print('End child')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It seems that it won't work under windows os.. am I right?